# Discrete Math question: Union of sets and transitivity of relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I put two questions in one post, I hope no one minds.

1. Let $U$ be an universe and let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of $U$ such that $A \cup B = A$. Then we can conclude

(A) $B$ is a subset of $A$

(B) $B = \emptyset$

(C) $A$ is a subset of $B$.

(D) $A = U$.

I know that (C) is not right. I also, think that (B) could be right but I can't infer (B) from the information given. So I think it is either (A) or (D). But both seem right to me. Can someone please explain why one or the other is the answer?

2. Only one of the following binary relations on the set $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$ is transitive. Which one?

(A) $R = (a,b),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b)\}$

(B) $R = \{(a,b),(b,c),(c,a),(a,c)\}$

(C) $R = \{(a,b),(a,a),(b,a)\}$

(D) $R = \{(a,b),(c,b)\}$

I know by definition of a transitive relation, (A) and (B) are incorrect. And by definition I think I know that (C) is correct. My question is about (D). Since there is no link in that relation to infer transitivity or intransitivity, isn't that the vacuous truth that the relation in (D) is transitive?

Thank you!

Comment: In your first question, part D refers to $D$.  Is that a typo?  What's really meant?  Your second question asks whether the relation is symmetric but you're talking about transitivity.  It's possible for a relation to be both transitive and symmetric so I don't understand why you're doing so.

Comment: @RobertShore Sorry for the confusion. I fixed it.

Comment: You're correct about the second question.  As to the first question, only one of the four statements is *always* true when $A \cup B = A$.  That's the one you want.

Comment: For the first question, continuing from your comment in the question, (A) is always true irrespective of $A=U$ or not.